# How do I pragmatically pair and connect a Bluetooth device. Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I've struggled to find an answer to this question for the latest flavors of Android.

I'd like to connect to a Bluetooth device or Bluetooth serial module, completely pragmatically. I know the name and pin of the device, and I intend to attempt to continually connect to the device in the case I'm initially out of range, or for some reason disconnect.

I have the following code and need to populate it with the necessary bluetooth code.

```
// Connect the bluetooth adaptor
    BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Checking bluetooth...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (!BA.isEnabled()) {
        Intent turnOn = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(turnOn, 0);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Adaptor enabled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Adaptor already enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

// Start a background thread that attempts to connect to the board
    Runnable bluetoothBackgroundRunnable = new Runnable() {
        String bluetoothID = "ID GOES HERE";   // TODO: Change this to device name!
        String securePin = "1234";             // TODO: Change this to device pin!
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Attempt to connect...
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Attempting to connect...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST);

            bluetoothConnectHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };
    bluetoothConnectHandler.postDelayed(bluetoothBackgroundRunnable, 100);
```